# VHDL dynamic range selection synthesizable code

Tags: vhdl

Working on a complex range selection logic.

There are too many combinations as select signals and too many ranges to choose and concatenate.

I am looking for a better way to make it readable, with meaningful variables which generated from pre-defined constants and dynamic inputs.

A simplified example as followings, not sure if it is synthesizable or not.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fum is
end entity;

architecture foo of fum is
    signal sel:             std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal selected_range:  std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);
    signal counter:         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

    constant BASE_ADDR_LOW: integer := 2;
    constant RANGE1_BITS  : integer := 2;
    -- this is simplified
    -- dozens of constants involved, and their values can be configured before compiling.
begin

some_process:
    process (sel, counter)
    variable range0_high : integer := BASE_ADDR_LOW;
    variable range1_low  : integer := 0;
    variable range1_high : integer := 0;
    begin

    if (sel = "00") then
    -- this is simpilfied as well
    -- dozens of inputs as sel involved, for 50+ combinations via nested if and case
        range0_high := BASE_ADDR_LOW+1; -- 3
        range1_low  := range0_high+2;   -- 5
        range1_high := range1_low+RANGE1_BITS-1; -- 6

    -- the following elsif will not work as the range1 has 0 bit.
    -- not sure if there is a better way to do this

    -- elsif (sel = "01" ) then
    --  range0_high := BASE_ADDR_LOW+1; -- 5
    --  range1_low  := range0_high+2;   -- N/A
    --  range1_high := range1_low+RANGE1_BITS;  --N/A
    else
        range0_high := BASE_ADDR_LOW;   -- 2
        range1_low  := range0_high+2;   -- 4
        range1_high := range1_low+RANGE1_BITS; --6
    end if;

    -- using variables in range
    selected_ranges <= counter(range1_high downto range1_low) & counter(range0_high downto 0);

    end process;
end architecture;
```

and is there any way to make a synthesizable code if some fields could be 0 bit?

```
-- e.g. range0_high = 5, range1_* not in use
-- selected_ranges <= *nothing &* counter(5 downto 0);
```

Comment: Waving your hands isn't helping.

Comment: If you're dealing with an unknown large number of conditions, you can write a program to express the combinations and look at them in tabular form, showing which contributing input and index goes to which output. It'll tell you how to document it and how to implement it to match. Synthesis literally only cares about one output bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Regardless you're overthinking the problem.

Your 'selected_ranges' is multiplexer with two possible values based on whether or not `sel = "00"`.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity fum is
end entity;

architecture foo of fum is
    signal sel:             std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal selected_range:  std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);
    signal counter:         std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
some_process:
    process (sel, counter)
    begin
        if sel = "00" then
            selected_range <= counter (6 downto 5) & counter (3 downto 0);
        else 
            selected_range <= counter (6 downto 4) & counter (2 downto 0);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This code analyzes, elaborates and runs, and by adding an initial value to `sel` of `"00"` and redoing, shows that the length of the expression of both alternatives is correct.

This will get even more simplified in synthesis noting the upper two and lower three 'bits' of `selected_range` are the same for both cases.

So, yes your code is synthesis eligible, no it isn't dynamically ranged (there are only one 'bit' that can be different based on `sel`, and those represent one 2:1 multiplexer driven by a two input gate looking at `sel`.

You simply chose a hard way to express what your code does. (And the expression here is still verbose).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Sorry about the incomplete example. I know it is a mux, but what I want to ask  is if I can use variables in range for a synthesizable code. Because the code I am working on has dozens signals involved as sel and the combinations for different ranges will be 50+. Such, I'd like to reduce some parts of it by generating ranges via constant and variables

Comment: Describe N muxes (potentially of varying lengths), by their number of different control conditions. Synthesis will still collapse as much as possible.  As long as `counter` has a static range there's no reason the conditions won't be either (and for each segment some number of static 'selects'). For all your generics and other constants you could express muxes in generate statements.

Comment: The more complex the multiplexing scheme the more you can construct it from smaller muxes, and about here you should be defining this is a design specification.  (It saves waving your hands around someone else's example).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a normal multiplexer with N inputs and describe it by selecting the result from an array containing the multiplexer data inputs (`mux_data_in`):

```
type t_mux_data_in is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(selected_range'range);
signal mux_data_in : t_mux_data_in(0 to N-1);
...
selected_range <= mux_data_in(to_integer(unsigned(sel)));
```

The multiplexer data inputs are generated with a `for .. generate` loop and some helper functions which specify the ranges for each iteration `i` in the loop. Within the loop you have to check whether range 1 is empty.

The full code is as follows with the ranges given in your example code. I had to modify the case `sel = "01"` to get an empty range 1, see my comments. The code synthesizes well in ISE 14.7 and actually a 6-bit 3-to-1 multiplexer is generated because case 2 and 3 are the same.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fum is
    generic (
        SEL_BITS : positive := 2);
    port (
        sel :            in  std_logic_vector (SEL_BITS-1 downto 0);
        counter :        in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        selected_range : out std_logic_vector (5 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture foo of fum is
    constant BASE_ADDR_LOW: integer := 2;
    constant RANGE1_BITS  : integer := 2;

    -- functions defining range
    function range0_high(sel : integer) return integer is
    begin
        case sel is
        when 0      => return BASE_ADDR_LOW+1;
        when 1      => return BASE_ADDR_LOW+3; -- updated to +3 to get a 5 (!)
        when others => return BASE_ADDR_LOW;   -- default
        end case;
    end function;

    function range1_low(sel : integer) return integer is
    begin
        return range0_high(sel)+2; -- default
    end function;

    function range1_high(sel : integer) return integer is
    begin
        case sel is
        when 0      => return range1_low(sel)+RANGE1_BITS-1;
        when 1      => return range1_low(sel);             -- updated to empty range (!)
        when others => return range1_low(sel)+RANGE1_BITS; -- default
        end case;
    end function;

    -- all multiplexer data inputs
    constant N : positive := 2**SEL_BITS;
    type t_mux_data_in is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(selected_range'range);
    signal mux_data_in : t_mux_data_in(0 to N-1);

begin
    -- build multiplexer data inputs
    genDataIn: for i in 0 to N-1 generate
        constant r1_low : integer := range1_low(i);
        constant r1_high: integer := range1_high(i);
    begin
        genHighEmpty: if r1_low = r1_high generate
            mux_data_in(i) <= counter(range0_high(i) downto 0);
        end generate;
        genHigh: if r1_low /= r1_high generate
            mux_data_in(i) <= counter(r1_high downto r1_low) & counter(range0_high(i) downto 0);
        end generate;
    end generate;

    -- the multiplexer
    selected_range <= mux_data_in(to_integer(unsigned(sel)));
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the idea of array and generate is great. I will give it a try.